# Distinct Union with null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that unions together some selects from two different tables

I currently end up with the final result as so:

```
    ColA      ColB    ColC
  -------------------------
1 | NULL      DEF      1
2 | ABC       DEF      1
3 | NULL      GBY      1
```

Column B will have a maximum of two records with the same value. In this case I would only like to select the record that doesn't have NULL for Column A.

Final Result would be:

```
    ColA      ColB    ColC
  -------------------------
1 | ABC       DEF      1
2 | NULL      GBY      1
```

So far I have surrounded the original union with a select and I presume I need some sort of WHERE, HAVING or GROUP BY.

Any ideas?

Comment: MAX(ColA), ColB group by ColB should do it.

Comment: should have explained there are other columns, it was just that A and B are the two important ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, 
         RN = row_number() over (partition by ColB Order By ColA DESC)
  FROM dbo.TableName -- or your query 
)
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[Sql-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e596f/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test
CREATE TABLE #test (Col1 char(10), col2 char(10))

INSERT INTO #test(Col1,col2) VALUES 
(NULL,'DEF'),
('ABC','ABC'),
(NULL,'DEF')

select distinct * from #test
where col2 is not null or col1 in (
  select col1 from #test
  group by col1
  having max(col2) is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
 select colA, max(colB) as colB, colC
 from table
 group by colA, colC
```